# Is it possible to deploy a daml smart contract with bots to Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: python, virtualenv, hyperledger-fabric, daml

I deployed quickstart tutorial based on the example "daml-on-fabric" https://github.com/hacera/daml-on-fabric and after that i tried to deploy the pingpong example from dazl https://github.com/digital-asset/dazl-client/tree/master/samples/ping-pong. The bots from the example works fine on daml ledger. However, when i try to deploy this example on fabric the bots are unable to send the transactions. Everything works fine based on this read me from https://github.com/hacera/daml-on-fabric/blob/master/README.md. The smart contract look like to be deployed on Fabric. The error is when i try to use the bots from pingpong python files https://github.com/digital-asset/dazl-client/blob/master/samples/ping-pong/README.md

```
I receive this error:

[  ERROR] 2020-03-10 15:40:57,475 | dazl    | A command submission failed!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vasisiop/.local/share/virtualenvs/ping-pong-sDNeps76/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dazl/client/_party_client_impl.py", line 415, in main_writer
    await submit_command_async(client, p, commands)
  File "/home/vasisiop/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/vasisiop/.local/share/virtualenvs/ping-pong-sDNeps76/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dazl/protocols/v1/grpc.py", line 42, in <lambda>
    lambda: self.connection.command_service.SubmitAndWait(request))
  File "/home/vasisiop/.local/share/virtualenvs/ping-pong-sDNeps76/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 824, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/home/vasisiop/.local/share/virtualenvs/ping-pong-sDNeps76/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 726, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
    details = "Party not known on ledger"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1583847657.473821297","description":"Error received from peer ipv6:[::1]:6865","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1056,"grpc_message":"Party not known on ledger","grpc_status":3}"
>

[  ERROR] 2020-03-10 15:40:57,476 | dazl    | An event handler in a bot has thrown an exception!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vasisiop/.local/share/virtualenvs/ping-pong-sDNeps76/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dazl/client/bots.py", line 157, in _handle_event
    await handler.callback(new_event)
  File "/home/vasisiop/.local/share/virtualenvs/ping-pong-sDNeps76/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dazl/client/_party_client_impl.py", line 415, in main_writer
    await submit_command_async(client, p, commands)
  File "/home/vasisiop/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/vasisiop/.local/share/virtualenvs/ping-pong-sDNeps76/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dazl/protocols/v1/grpc.py", line 42, in <lambda>
    lambda: self.connection.command_service.SubmitAndWait(request))
  File "/home/vasisiop/.local/share/virtualenvs/ping-pong-sDNeps76/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 824, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/home/vasisiop/.local/share/virtualenvs/ping-pong-sDNeps76/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 726, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
    details = "Party not known on ledger"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1583847657.473821297","description":"Error received from peer ipv6:[::1]:6865","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1056,"grpc_message":"Party not known on ledger","grpc_status":3}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error message it looks like the parties defined in the quick start example have not been allocated on the ledger, hence the "Party not known on ledger" error.

You can follow the steps in https://docs.daml.com/deploy/index.html with use of  daml deploy --host= --port=, which will both upload the dars and allocate the parties on the ledger.

You can also run just the allocate party command daml ledger allocate-parties, which will allocate based on the parties defined you your daml.yaml.

Comment: @HectorCode does the daml dazl bot get deployed in hyperledger fabric? Is the smart contract written in DAML or HLF?